# How to upload react build folder to my remote server?

Tags: reactjs, django, ubuntu, frontend, backend

I'm trying to deploy my react build folder to my server. I'm using index.html and static that configured in my settings.py file to do that. (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

Since my backend is running on Ubuntu, I can't just copy from my Windows side and paste it. For now, I uploaded my build folder to my Google Drive and I download it on Ubuntu. But I still can't just copy and paste it on my PyCharm IDE, I can only copy the content in each file and then create a new file ony my server and paste the content to the file. This is just so time-consuming.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use scp to upload the floder to remote

This link may help you：

https://linuxhandbook.com/transfer-files-ssh/

Answer (score 2):

use `scp` command

```bash
# in dest folder:
scp username@remove_address:/path/for/deploy ./
```